¿Posible solucion (1054, "Unknown column 'catalogo_categoria.lft' in 'where clause'") con django mptt?
Estoy usando django mptt en su version 0.16.0 para tener una categoria en forma de arbol, el modelo que estoy usando:
from django.db import models 
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey 
class Categoria(MPTTModel): 
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='subcategoria', verbose_name="padre") 
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="categorias/",null=True,blank=True) 
class MPTTMeta: 
   order_insertion_by = ['nombre'] 
 def str(self): 
   return self.nombre

Y al usarlo pasarlo a producción me dice:

1054, "Unknown column 'catalogo_categoria.lft' in 'where clause'"

Revise en la BD que tengo que es MariaDB de PHPMyAdmin y si se encuentra esa columna. Adjunto una imagen de la tabla:

Como extra estoy usando también django-unfold en el admin.
Probé recrear la Base de Datos, elimnando las migraciones y creando de 0.
Probé haciendo un rebuild().
El error creo que se encuentra en mi Base de datos por que usando SQLite o MySQL con workbench funcionan correctamente.

Al pasarlo a producción? realizaste todas las configuraciones para eso? las migraciones si es que tenians que hacerlas?

Si cambie las configuraciones en DATABASES, realice el makemigrations, el migrate, e inculos elimine las migraciones y las volvi a hacerlas.

Motor de la BD y la tabla? version de mariadb?  para mi tiene que ver con algo de la configuracion y las migraciones, pero no se que pueda ser.
